# Java: ImageIcon vs. Image difference

Tags: java, image, swing, awt, imageicon

Could anyone explain to me in noob way what the difference is betweeen **ImageIcon** and **Image** classes/objects in Java? Thanks

Comment: Is this homework? Everything needed to answer this question should be documented in the javadocs.

Comment: No it is not a homework. For this question like for the great majority of  my other questions  regarding Java, the info can be found in javadocs. But if I could understand everything from javadocs I wouldnt need any books, forums, or google or even internet for that matter.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Their nature and application is different. [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) is an abstract superclass of all classes that represent graphical images. [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html) is an implementation of `Icon` interface that uses `Image` as its source.

Edit: Think of an `Image` as something that *could* be rendered and an `ImageIcon` as something that *will* be rendered as an `Icon` when its `paintIcon()` method is called.

Edit: The links above will take you to the JDK 6 api. These links will take you to the JDK 8 api: [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html) and [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html).

Comment: Ok so `ImageIcon` object has an underlying `Image` object and provides an extra layer with methods to manipulate this image? Also, `Icon` can be implemented in number of ways and not necessarily to have the underlying image (for example painting a label or rectangle). Or am I wrong? I just don't fully understand, if icon is just a small image, why to have two different classes for that.

Comment: @LeNoob `Icon` is typically used to decorate components (labels, buttons, etc), i.e. they are painted on something. `Image`, on the other hand, is not only for displaying, it can be used to draw on it. Take a look at [Images](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/images.html) tutorial for some examples. [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) can also be useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can scale and save Image, but you can't do it with ImageIcon. For creating pictures in your GUI you usually have to use ImageIcon, but if you don't wanna do that, Image should be better.

Comment: But if `ImageIcon` has underlying image, how come I cannot save it and scale it?